# Angular 2: Apply CSS to only selected item from *ngFor array

Tags: angular

I'm working on my first angular app... It's a price estimate calculator for different kinds of construction jobs. Im trying to make it so that only the selected card gets special CSS (such as a reduced opacity).

I tried doing this by setting up an empty status variable in the class that gets updated to the value of the chosen card's name, then checking if the status name is equal to the status variable and applying an "active" css to it... but it's currently applying the class to every card upon clicking and not just the clicked card.

Can anyone help me out on where I went wrong? [View of the app so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6zRF.png)

```
//Component.ts

export class EstimateChoices {

option: string;
status: string = '';

drivewayOptions = 
    [{name:'Driveway Addition (End)', imageSrc:'./assets/images/driveway-1.png'},
     {name:'Driveway Addition (Width)', imageSrc:'./assets/images/driveway-2.png'},
     {name:'New Driveway', imageSrc:'./assets/images/driveway-3.png'},
     {name:'Section Replace', imageSrc:'./assets/images/driveway-4.png'},
     {name:'Driveway Addition (Pad)', imageSrc:'./assets/images/driveway-5.png'},
     {name:'New Driveway (Round)', imageSrc:'./assets/images/driveway-6.png'},
     {name:'Driveway Addition (Round)', imageSrc:'./assets/images/driveway-7.png'}];

sidewalkOptions = 
    [{name:'New Sidewalk', imageSrc:'./assets/images/sidewalk-1.png'},
     {name:'New Sidewalk (Curved)', imageSrc:'./assets/images/sidewalk-2.png'},
     {name:'New Sidewalk (Angled)', imageSrc:'./assets/images/sidewalk-3.png'},
     {name:'Section Replace', imageSrc:'./assets/images/sidewalk-4.png'}];

patioOptions = 
    [{name:'New Patio (Round)', imageSrc:'./assets/images/patio-1.png'},
     {name:'New Patio', imageSrc:'./assets/images/patio-2.png'},
     {name:'New Patio (Round End)', imageSrc:'./assets/images/patio-3.png'},
     {name:'New Patio (Oval)', imageSrc:'./assets/images/patio-4.png'},
     {name:'Patio Addition (Round End)', imageSrc:'./assets/images/patio-5.png'},
     {name:'Patio Addition', imageSrc:'./assets/images/patio-6.png'}];

poolOptions = 
    [{name:'Pool Deck Replacement', imageSrc:'./assets/images/pool-1.png'}];

hotTubOptions = 
    [{name:'New Hot Tub Pad', imageSrc:'./assets/images/hot-tub-pad-1.png'},
     {name:'New Pad (Round)', imageSrc:'./assets/images/hot-tub-pad-2.png'}];

onSelect(option: string) {
this.option = option;
}

}
```

This is a component.html snippet for the driveway job types...

```
<div class="options-container driveway-options" *ngIf="option === 'driveways'">
    <div *ngFor="let drivewayOption of drivewayOptions" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="option-card" [class.active]="status==='drivewayOption.name'" 
(click)="status='drivewayOption.name'">
            <img class="estimate-option-image" [src]="drivewayOption.imageSrc">
            <p>{{drivewayOption.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>                               
</div>
```

Comment: use `[ngClass]="{ active' : status===drivewayOption.name}"` instead of  `[class.active]`. Also, you need to remove the single quotes from `click` event, should be `(click)="status=drivewayOption.name"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `status='drivewayOption.name'"` which makes the right hand side just a string instead of the  drivewayOption.name.Hence you have to do

```
(click)="status=drivewayOption.name" without the quotes and


status===drivewayOption.name without the quotes as wel
```

Incase if this doesn't workout try this

```
<div class="options-container driveway-options" *ngIf="option === 'driveways'">
<div *ngFor="let drivewayOption of drivewayOptions" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="option-card" [class.active]="status===activeVariable" 

(click)="setActiveVariable({drivewayOption.name)">
        <img class="estimate-option-image" [src]="drivewayOption.imageSrc">
        <p>{{drivewayOption.name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the component

```
setActiveVariable(value){
 this.activeVariable=value;
}
```

should do the trick

Comment: Wow... Thanks so much. Removing those quotes worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a boolean on your component like `isSelected`, then you switch it to `true` when your event occurs and you add the css class when the variable is true:

```
<div class="row" [ngClass]="{row_selected: isSelected}"></div>
```